# Using ClojureScript core.async channels from Javascript

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, core.async

I'm trying to use a cljs library from a Node.js, Electron project.

A function I'm calling in the cljs library returns a `core.async` channel object. It looks like this when I `console.log`:

```
{
  takes: { head: 0, tail: 0, length: 0, arr: [ <32 empty items> ] },
  dirty_takes: 0,
  puts: { head: 0, tail: 0, length: 0, arr: [ <32 empty items> ] },
  dirty_puts: 0,
  buf: {
    buf: { head: 0, tail: 0, length: 0, arr: [Array] },
    n: 1,
    'cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$': 2,
    'cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$': 0
  },
  closed: false,
  add_BANG_: [Function: G__11914] {
    'cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$1': [Function: G__11914__1],
    'cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$2': [Function: G__11914__2]
  }
}
```

How can I interact with it from Javascript?
How to do something like `(take! channel callback)` in js?

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially do this if you have access to the `cljs.core.async` namespace from JS.

```
;; CLJS
(take! channel callback)
;; JS
cljs.core.async.take_BANG_(channel, function(val) { console.log(val); });
```